# Append SerialDataReceivedEventHandler into list to return to main method

Tags: c#, serial-port

I get empty and null value on  `string[] toArray = tagList.ToArray();` when `tagList` is called on ReadTag() function.

What I want to do is return a list of string array from ReadTag() to my main method. The `port_DataReceived` seems like does not return any List to ReadTag's function `tagList`. Guess this is a stupid question, please help. Thanks

Code for ReadTag() function:

```
 List<string> tagList = new List<string>();
    public string[] Readtag()
    {
        
        //port connections option
        _serialPort.WriteLine("RLD");
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
        string[] toArray = tagList.ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(tagList);
        return toArray;
    }
```

Code for port_DataReceived:

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       
        var result = string.Empty;
        result += _serialPort.ReadExisting();

        while (result.Contains(@"TID"))
        {
            var slashPos = result.IndexOf(@"TID", 1);
            result = result.Replace("TID ", "");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            tagList.Add(result);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: All kinds of problems here, but the chief issue is that an event handler doesn't run immediately, it runs when the event happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution which is sleep the Thread for few seconds to allowed EventHandler to append all result into the tagList before display.